HTTP Request Error: InternalServerError Internal server error: An error occurred while saving the entity changes

HTTP Request Error: InternalServerError Internal server error: An
error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner
exception for details.

i got this error while trying to save into database from Xamarin android form
Startup.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using PFAG1_2Cars.Core.Repositories;
using PFAG1_2Cars.Core.Services;
using PFAG1_2Cars.Core;
using PFAG1_2Cars.Data;
using PFAG1_2Cars.Data.Repositories;
using PFAG1_2Cars.Data.UnitOfWork;
using PFAG1_2Cars.Services.Services;

namespace Web.API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Configure DbContext
            services.AddDbContext<PFAG1_2CarsDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            // Register repositories
            services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
            services.AddScoped<IAssuranceRepository, AssuranceRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IRoleRepository, RoleRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ICategorieRepository, CategorieRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ICompanyAssuranceRepository, CompanyAssuranceRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ICompteRepository, CompteRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IControleTechniqueRepository, ControleTechniqueRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IInterventionRepository, InterventionRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IMarqueRepository, MarqueRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IModelRepository, ModelRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IPrestationRepository, PrestationRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ICarRepository, CarRepository>();

            // Register services
            services.AddScoped<IAssuranceService, AssuranceService>();
            services.AddScoped<IRoleService, RoleService>();
            services.AddScoped<ICategorieService, CategoryService>();
            services.AddScoped<ICompanyAssuranceService, CompanyAssuranceService>();
            services.AddScoped<ICompteService, CompteService>();
            services.AddScoped<IControleTechniqueService, ControleTechniqueService>();
            services.AddScoped<IInterventionService, InterventionService>();
            services.AddScoped<IMarqueService, MarqueService>();
            services.AddScoped<IModelService, ModelService>();
            services.AddScoped<IPrestationService, PrestationService>();
            services.AddScoped<ICarService, CarService>();

            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddLogging();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}

Program.cs :
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace Web.API
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.AddConsole(); // Output to console
                logging.AddDebug();  // Output to debug window
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.UseUrls("http://192.168.x.x:5050");
            });
    }
}

appsettings.json :
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=192.168.x.x\\SQLEXPRESS,1433;Database=xxx;User Id=xxx;Password=xxx;Encrypt=False;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApiBaseUrl": "https://192.168.x.x:5050/api/"
}


YourController :
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using PFAG1_2Cars.Core.Entities;
using PFAG1_2Cars.Core.Services;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Web.API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class YourController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IMarqueService _marqueService;
        private readonly ILogger<YourController> _logger;

        public YourController(IMarqueService marqueService, ILogger<YourController> logger)
        {
            _marqueService = marqueService;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        // GET: api/your
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Marque>>> GetMarques()
        {
            try
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Getting all marques");
                var marques = await _marqueService.GetAllMarques();
                return Ok(marques);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while getting marques.");
                return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        // GET: api/your/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Marque>> GetMarque(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"Getting marque with ID {id}");
                var marque = await _marqueService.GetMarqueById(id);
                if (marque == null)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning($"Marque with ID {id} not found.");
                    return NotFound();
                }
                return Ok(marque);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, $"An error occurred while getting marque with ID {id}.");
                return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        // POST: api/your
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Marque>> PostMarque(Marque marque)
        {
            try
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Creating a new marque");
                var newMarque = await _marqueService.CreateMarque(marque);
                return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetMarque), new { id = newMarque.IdMarque }, newMarque);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while creating a new marque.");
                return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        // PUT: api/your/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutMarque(int id, Marque marque)
        {
            try
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"Updating marque with ID {id}");
                await _marqueService.UpdateMarque(new Marque { IdMarque = id }, marque);
                return NoContent();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, $"An error occurred while updating marque with ID {id}.");
                return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        // DELETE: api/your/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteMarque(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"Deleting marque with ID {id}");
                await _marqueService.DeleteMarqueById(id);
                return NoContent();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, $"An error occurred while deleting marque with ID {id}.");
                return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}


MarqueForm.xaml :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TEST.MarqueForm">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Padding="20">
            <Entry x:Name="IdMarqueEntry" Placeholder="Enter Id Marque" Keyboard="Numeric" />
            <Entry x:Name="NomMarqueEntry" Placeholder="Enter Nom Marque" />
            <Button Text="Submit" Clicked="OnSubmitClicked" />
            <Label x:Name="ResultLabel" Text="Result will be displayed here" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>


MarqueForm.xaml.cs :
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using PFAG1_2Cars.Core.Entities;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TEST
{
    public partial class MarqueForm : ContentPage
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

        public MarqueForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _httpClient = new HttpClient();
            _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://192.168.1.100:5050/api/your"); // Adjust base URL as needed
        }

        private async void OnSubmitClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!int.TryParse(IdMarqueEntry.Text, out int idMarque))
                {
                    ResultLabel.Text = "Invalid Id Marque. Please enter a valid integer.";
                    return;
                }

                var marque = new Marque
                {
                    IdMarque = idMarque,
                    NomMarque = NomMarqueEntry.Text
                };

                await PostMarqueAsync(marque);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ResultLabel.Text = $"Exception: {ex.Message}";
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        private async Task PostMarqueAsync(Marque marque)
        {
            try
            {
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(marque);
                var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("", content); // Adjust endpoint if necessary

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    ResultLabel.Text = "Marque added successfully!";
                }
                else
                {
                    var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    ResultLabel.Text = $"Error: {response.StatusCode}\n{responseContent}";

                    // Log the error to the console
                    Console.WriteLine($"HTTP Request Error: {response.StatusCode}\n{responseContent}");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ResultLabel.Text = $"Exception: {ex.Message}";
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}


i tried the post method with the following url : http://192.168.x.x:5050/api/your
in Postman, pc's browser and phone's browser

Put a breakpoint on this line: var newMarque = await _marqueService.CreateMarque(marque); then STEP through that method.

EF loves to hide exceptions in InnerException, so the error details is actually there, but your log won't output it. When dealing with this kinda exceptions, you either consider:

Use debugger and breakpoints to see the run-time exception detail.
Make sure you're getting InnerException which contains actual messages.

For method 2, here's a little tool I use to handle exceptions logging in middlewares,
    public static string GetActualMessage(this Exception e)
    {
        if (e.InnerException == null)
            return e.Message;

        HashSet<Exception> traversed = new();
        Exception current = e;

        while (traversed.Add(current) && current.InnerException != null)
        {
            current = current.InnerException;
        }

        return current.Message;
    }

Using it to get acutal messages could be like this,
try {
  // ...
} catch (Exception e) {
  Console.WriteLine(e.GetActualMessage());
}


Use debugger and ensure that connection string is valid(Username and password)
